# Convert multi dimensional array to organized arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert an array in this format:

```
Array ( 
    [size] => P 
    [code] => Array ( 
        [0] => C01 
        [1] => B01 
        [2] = A02
    ) 
)
```

to multiple ones like this:

```
Array ( [size] => P [code] => C01 )
Array ( [size] => P [code] => B01 )
Array ( [size] => P [code] => A02 )
```

How would I do that using php code?

Comment: Using loops. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop throught items of `code` array and push values into new array or new variable.

```
foreach($arr["code"] as $item){
    @$newArr[] = [
        "size" => "P",
        "code" => $item
    ];
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Check code result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/itpEC)

Comment: How to create variables by foreach loop? That is why i did not use a `foreach` loop

Comment: @AniketSahrawat As you can see, i push values in `$newArr` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$original = Array (
                'size' => 'P',
                'code' => Array (
                        0 => 'C01',
                        1 => 'B01',
                        2 => 'A02',
                )
            );
$newArray = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($original['code']); $i++){
    $newArray[$i]['size'] = $original['size'];
    $newArray[$i]['code'] = $original['code'][$i];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

//Array ( [0] => Array ( [size] => P [code] => C01 ) [1] => Array ( [size] => P [code] => B01 ) [2] => Array ( [size] => P [code] => A02 ) )

You can loop through the resulting array to get results